# How can I prove that m, n in $m^2 = 6n^2$ are not integers?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, integers

Having $n, m \neq 0 $ and $m^2 = 6n^2 $

How do I prove that $ n,m \notin \Bbb Z$  using somewhat formal methods?

Comment: If I prove the irrationality of $\sqrt 6$ do I have to prove that any integer multiplied by an irrational number equals another irrational number or is it trivial?

Comment: It’s trivial:  if $n\sqrt6=q,$ then $\sqrt6=q/n$

Comment: @fleablood:  $\sqrt3$ is not an integer

Comment: Whoops I read that as "irrational times irrational".  Not "integer times irrational". Oh, that's ... If you have to ask if you have to prove it, it is not trivial.  But if $nx = m$ where $x$ is irrational and $n$ is an integer.  Then $x = \frac mn$.  If $m$ were rational than $x$ would be.  But $x$ isn't so $m$ can't be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $m$ must be even. Then show that $n$ must be even.

Cancel and repeat.

Comment: To piggyback off this idea, you will need $d = \operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$ at some point. Choose integers $a,b$ such that $ad=m, bd=n$. Now, $a,b$ are relatively prime, and you can find a contradiction.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Or you can show by induction that you can cancel $2^k$ for each $k \geq 1$. But at some point $2^k >n$ ;)